# How to filter HTML Event in Native PHP7

Tags: php, xss, javascript, html, regex

i want to creating xss filter for my own project, this is for html event filtering

```
preg_replace("/ on\w+='[^']*'/i", '', preg_replace('/ on\w+="[^"]*"/i', '', $framed));
```

but considering to more efective way, i would think this is more efectively clearing unquoted attribute like this

```
preg_replace('/on\w+=/i', '', $framed);
```

but i think would be another way that more efective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correctly filtering XSS from input is pretty hard. Most XSS filters can be bypassed by modifying the payload. For example, the following HTML will pass through your XSS filter:

```
<h1 onmouseover =alert`XSS`>Test</h1>
```

Because there is a space between `onmouseover` and `=`, your regex doesn't match. Another possible bypass is this:

```
<h1 oonmouseover=nmouseover=alert`XSS`>Test</h1>
```

The occurrence of `onmouseover=` will be removed once, leaving the following:

```
<h1 onmouseover=alert`XSS`>Test</h1>
```

One possibility is to use [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), a library that is pretty good at cleaning up XSS. But the real solution against XSS is output encoding, so that when a user enters `<script>alert(1)`, it just appears on the webpage as `<script>alert(1)` instead of being parsed as HTML.

Comment: i would think if i just filter the html event and replacing with string rather than deleting them in native.